# best method for ajax loops

Tags: jquery, ajax, loops

Im building a web app with some real-time features, chat, auto updating lists. What's the best way to do these interval updates via AJAX?

Right now I have something basic like:

```
updateAll();

function updateAll(){
 $.ajax({
  url: 'update-chat-list.php',
  success: function(data){
     setTimeout(function(){ updateAll(); },30000);
  }
 });
}
```

This seems like it does the job, but is this the most efficient way to keep hitting the server for requests to update the page?

Comment: OT: You could just write  `setTimeout(updateAll, 30000);` (if you are not passing any parameters not shown in this example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most efficient way is to degrade gracefully:

1) Attempt to use the [Web Sockets API](http://websocket.org/) for adding push functionality and real-time updates without a loop. This is the best solution for modern browsers right now.

2) Use an Ajax loop. You can improve your current code slightly by using `setInterval` instead of repeatedly calling `setTimeout`.

3) Fall back to timed page refreshes, `<iframe>`s or manual refreshes.

So, you can keep what you've got, but learn about the [Web Sockets API](http://websocket.org/).

Comment: I ended up playing around with socket.io with node.js and it's proving to be a very effective method.